# How can i reduce the bits size sent in a local simulation In unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, simulation

I’m working on a project where I’m sending player positions to the remote player which is based on local simulation.
The size of bits sent to the remote player is 96 bits. (32 * 3 floats) = 96.
How can I reduce the size of the bits being shared from player to remote

I want to reduce the bits being share to the remote player

Comment: well you can't really .. if you need that amount of floats without having information loss .. well then you need to include all information ... a bit unclear what you are asking exactly

Comment: 96 Bits, that's 12 bytes. Why do you care? The IPv4 header already has 20 bytes.